# Can't replace ../ in mySQL with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do a REPLACE using:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE (post_content, 'src=..\wp-content','src='wp-content')
```

And the database says it is successful, but with 0 rows affected.

I can search directly for `%..\wp-content%` in post_content and find the entries so I know they exist.

How do I find/replace these entries (`..\wp-content`)?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does your `post_content` data look like?  Are you *sure* the string is exactly `"src=..\wp-content"`?

Comment: start by escaping your single quotes in your `src='wp-content'` and your `\\` character

Answer (score 3):

You have to double-escape your backslashes.

```
UPDATE .... 'src=..\\wp-content'etc...
```

since `\w` isn't an sql metacharacter, the sql parser will reduce that to a simple `w`.

e.g.

```
mysql> create table foo (x varchar(16));

mysql> insert into foo (x) values ('foo\war'), ('foo\\war');

mysql> select * from foo;
+---------+
| x       |
+---------+
| foowar  |
| foo\war |
+---------+
```

Note how the single backslash has now vanished, and it's just `foowar` in the table. Which means that your `where` clause:

```
mysql> select * from foo where x='foo\war';
+--------+
| x      |
+--------+
| foowar |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from foo where x='foo\\war';
+---------+
| x       |
+---------+
| foo\war |
+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks!  I changed my statement to:  UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'src=..\\wp-content','src=wp-content')   No change.  I had tried this before.  The content in the table looks like this:  <a href="../wp-content/uploads/8/663.jpg"><img src="../wp-content/uploads/8/663.jpg" alt="" /></a>

Comment: Thanks!  I changed my statement to:  UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content,'src=..\\wp-content','src=wp-content')   No change.  I had tried this before.  The content in the table looks like this:  <a href="../wp-content/uploads/8/663.jpg"><img src="../wp-content/uploads/8/663.jpg" alt="" /></a>  I just need to remove the "../" from the lines.  Sorry for jumble of text, but hitting return ends my comments here - and I have to hit edit again.  Thanks again!

Comment: you can edit a comment (within a time limit) by clicking the little pencil icon. and you can also edit your question to append more stuff, instead of dumping code into a comment (where it's pretty unreadable).